# ReactJS: looping through object. Why "item" didnt work as variable inside push metod?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects

I have some data in a firebase cloud firestore. 
This data i want to place in my react SPA as a paginated list. 
Exemple of data:

```
items {
    item1{
        descrHead: "white square",
        descrText: "lorem",
        imageUrl: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/whiteSquare-min.png",
        status: "available"
    },
    item2{
        descrHead: "blue square",
        descrText: "lorem",
        imageUrl: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/blueSquare-min.png",
        status: "available"
    },
    ...
    item N
}
```

I'm newbie in JS and I don’t have clear understanding how to work with objects.
I trying to do it using forEach and forIn loops:

```
getDataFromDB() {
    db.collection("items").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        let newState = [];

        // this test shows that connection works, 
        // we see the table with the first element data
        console.table(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());

        let allRecivedData = querySnapshot.docs; 

        allRecivedData.forEach((key)=>{

            let items = key.data();
            for (let item in items) {

                // this test shows me 
                // 80 correct pairs key:value
                console.log(`${item}: ${items[item]}`)

                newState.push({
                    item: items[item]
                });
            }
        })

        this.setState({
            items: newState
        });
    }
}
```

Now in my state this:

```
state
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    items: 
    |--0: {...}
        |--item: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/whiteSquare-min.png"
    |--1: {...}
        |--item: "white square"
    |--2: {...}
        |--item: descrText: "lorem"
    |--3: {...}
        |--item: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/whiteSquare-min.png"
    |--4: {...}
        |--item: "blue square"
    |--5: {...}
        |--item: descrText: "lorem"
    ...
```

Why all this items is starting from word "item"?
Why "item" didnt work as variable inside push metod?
How to split "items" in a blocks: item1{}, item2{}...?

When my component did mount i want to recive data from server and push it to the component state. 
Expected state:

```
state
    loading: true,
    error: false,
    items: 
    |--item1: 
        |--imageUrl: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/whiteSquare-min.png",
        |--descrHead: "white square",
        |--descrText: "lorem"
    |--item2: 
        |--imageUrl: "assets/portfolio/mini-stubs/whiteSquare-min.png",
        |--descrHead: "blue square",
        |--descrText: "lorem"
    ...
    |--itemN:
```

Comment: I think you are mixing arrays and object up. Can you add an example of the `state` please.

Comment: when you push `{ item: items[item]} ` you're creating a new object with the name "item". That is way all your object have that name, rather than item1, item2, item3 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
 newState.push({
                    item: items[item]
                });
```

you're pushing a new object with a property named `item`, containing your item of your iteration. You're not preserving the name.
Then, you are pushing that array of objects with the property name `item` into another object in your state, named items. That's done here

```
this.setState({
            items: newState
        });
```

I think you should use an object, rather than an array, so you can index by property rather than by numeric indexes. However, you are trying to use the exact same object in the state, so why don't you assign it directly?

```
let newState = {};
allRecivedData.forEach((key)=>{

    let items = key.data();
    this.setState(prevState => ({ items: { ...prevState.items, ...items } }));
})
```

with `...prevState.items` you're preserving previous items, and with `...items` you're extending it with the new ones, preserving the names.

Then you don't need anymore to use the newState variable.